# How to redirect page after login using react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Good evening! I am having some trouble trying to redirect the user correctly. If the user is not logged in, then the website redirects the user directly to the login page. After the user is logged in, they are redirected to a page. However, whenever the tries to directly access a page using any link, it's always redirected to the same page after the login.

`index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`App.js`

```
...
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  );

  if (props.isUserAuth) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/dashboard/"
          render={() => (
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
              <Dashboard />
            </Suspense>
          )}
        />
        <Redirect to="/dashboard/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return ({routes});
```

`dashboard.js`

```
      <div className={classes.offset}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard/quotes" component={Quotes} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/quotes/addquote" component={AddQuote} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/quotes/:id" component={EditQuote} />
          ...
          <Redirect exact from="/dashboard/" to="/dashboard/quotes" />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
```

**Problem**

App.js is actually redirecting the user to "/dashboard/" which is always redirecting the user to "/dashboard/quotes", no matter if the user access a different link as you can see on the code above. 
The login component is redirecting the user correctly whenever they are logged in or not. However, if the user that is already logged in tries to access directly a link (Ex: "/dashboard/something/id") they are always redirected to "/dashboard/quotes" no matter what.

I am using  component in `index.js` file which does not allow direct link access (according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/5574597)) After changing it to HashRouter, it seems to have fixed the problem (Despite the # in the URL). But according to the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter), it says that we should only use this to support legacy browsers, so I am not sure if it's a correct answer.

**[Here is the CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ellis-qlbd4?file=/src/App.js)**

I am not sure how I can solve this trouble. Can someone please help me out?
I really appreciate the help and time!

**Solution**

Turns out I was doing the routing wrong. Redirecting was working correctly at a certain point but when using Switch as it was, it did not change correctly. Here is my solution:

`app.js`

```
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  );

  if (props.isUserAuth) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={() => (
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
              <Dashboard />
            </Suspense>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

`dashboard.js`

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/quotes" component={Quotes} />
          <Route path="/quotes/addquote" component={AddQuote} />
          <Route path="/quotes/:id" component={EditQuote} />
  ...

          {/* Home Route */}
          <Route exact path="/" component={Quotes} />

          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do something like this if you do not want to maintain an extra state variable.

```js
function Component() {
    const history = useHistory();

    // pass this function to the event handler.
    function doSomething() {
        history.push('/dashboard/quotes')
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have made a mistake when developing the question. I am sorry about this.
Login is redirecting correctly whenever the user is logged on or not. However, if the user that is already logged in tries to access directly a link (Ex: "/dashboard/something/id") they are always redirected to "/dashboard/quotes" no matter what. I don't know how to solve this problem! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you mind creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? The thing that I am most certain about is that there is problem in your Router.

Comment: There! I have added the codesandbox with the related problem https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ellis-qlbd4?file=/src/App.js I am quite sure the problem is with the Route and Redirecting. I have seen that I could get the URL with useLocation, however, I don't how to redirect the user to the URL he first entered with it.

Comment: I had to fork your sandbox since I couldn't update that directly but you can find a forked one [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-flower-pnd9y?file=/src/App.js). I have written comments wherever I made the changes and now it works as you have intended.

Comment: Especially check out the `App.js` and `Dashboard.js` files.

Comment: I have checked the files you did, thanks! Although I could not find a solution there for my problem, I did not know that the BrowserHistory component I am using does not allow direct link access (accordingly to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/5574597 ) I have used HashBrowser and it seems to have fixed the problem (Despite the # in the URL). But in the documentation you have given me before, it says that we should only use this to support legacy browsers. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter 
I am really running out of options. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: BrowserRouter* and HashRouter*. Sorry.

Comment: Can you explain clearly through the codesandbox what exactly you are missing? It is becoming confusing for me as well to follow along.

Comment: Turns out that I was using a routing that somehow worked until a certain point. With the codesandbox you added, I managed to see where exactly it was the mistake and fix the routing right after. I have added the solution in the question above. I do appreciate the help. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could be of help!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and this worked for me.

This is in the login component in react

```
if(state  == logged in){
  <Redirect to="/dashboard/quotes" />
}
```

you check the logged-in state if there is a user redirect instantly

Comment: I think I have made a mistake when developing the question. I am sorry about this.
Login is redirecting correctly whenever the user is logged on or not. However, if the user that is already logged in tries to access directly a link (Ex: "/dashboard/something/id") they are always redirected to "/dashboard/quotes" no matter what. I don't know how to solve this problem! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Then look in your code for conditions that redirect to"/dashboard/quotes" it might be always true of you might have put it in a "setInterval" call back.

Comment: I am not sure how I could use setInterval with it. The problem is definitively with the Route and Redirecting that I am using. I have seen that I could get the URL with useLocation, however, I don't how to redirect the user to the URL he first entered with it. I have added the codesandbox with the related problem https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ellis-qlbd4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in Dashboard.js line 20
<Redirect exact from="/dashboard/" to="/dashboard/site1" />

every time the component loads it redirects to /site1 
you need to remove it or call it on a certain condition
I think that might solve your problem

Comment: Indeed that is the problem. However, how can I redirect the user to the exact same URL he tried to access first? I tried to use useLocation, but it keeps changing to different URLs over and over.